# Mocking a method with different signatures where one has Object as a parameter type

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, nunit, moq

I have the following interfaces

```
public interface IInfo
{
    bool IsCompatibleWith (Object informationObject);
}

public interface IInfo<T> : IInfo
{
    bool IsCompatibleWith (T informationObject);
}
```

and try to do the following Mocks

```
Foo f = new Foo();
Mock<IInfo<Foo>> infoMock = new Mock<IInfo<Foo>>();
infoMock.Setup(i => i.IsCompatibleWith(f)).Returns(true);
```

The test is then running the following lines

```
IInfo mockedInfo;
mockedInfo.IsCompatibleWith(f);
```

The problem is, that the Setup method sets up the `IsCompatibleWith (T informationObject)`, while the code is calling the `IsCompatibleWith (Object informationObject)` one. How can I setup both signatures?

Comment: Hi @user1039462, my edit rejected with a explanation that I had to point out that `Mock<IInfo<IModel>> infoMock = new Mock<IInfo<Foo>>()` doesn't compile(instead of edit your post), please change the code to `Mock<IInfo<IModel>> infoMock = new Mock<IInfo<IModel>>()` or `Mock<IInfo<Foo>> infoMock = new Mock<IInfo<Foo>>()`. Another thing the tag `mono` should be replace with the `mocking` tag. One more thing, if you need any clarification about my answer(below) feel free to ask....

Comment: @Old Fox: Did that, thanks for pointing out the errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following snippet shows the way to configure both methods:

```
//configure the method with the `object` as a parameter
infoMock.Setup(i => i.IsCompatibleWith((object)f)).Returns(true);

//configure the method with the `IModel` as a parameter
infoMock.Setup(i => i.IsCompatibleWith(f)).Returns(true);
```

`Moq` records the arguments as is. When you cast your instance to `object`, the method `bool IsCompatibleWith(Object informationObject)` will accept the registration